# JTable cell does get focus on mouse click

Tags: java, swing, jtable, focus, selection

I have a simple table and a button in a panel.  When I click on a table cell, I can edit it but the cell doesn't have the focus.  I want to be able to save the cell content if it is changed by the user, but I can only do this if I first tab into the cell to get the focus, and then select it with a mouse click.  I would like to just be able to click the cell and have any changes saved on exiting the cell.
When the button is clicked it displays the saved table cell contents.

Here is my code:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import static javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
    import javax.swing.table.*;

    public class TestFocus {

        public ArrayList<String> mylog;

        public TestFocus() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            JPanel panel = createPanel();
            frame.add(panel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);    
        }

        public JPanel createPanel() {
            mylog = new ArrayList<>();
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            TestTableModel tm = new TestTableModel();
            JLabel title = new JLabel("Test Table");
            JTable table = new JTable(tm);
            TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();
            TestTableCellEditor editor = new TestTableCellEditor();
            TestTableCellRenderer renderer = new TestTableCellRenderer();
            for (int i = 0; i < tm.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                TableColumn column = tcm.getColumn(i);
                column.setCellEditor(editor);
                column.setCellRenderer(renderer);
            }

            JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(table);

            JButton btn = new JButton("Done");
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    for (String s : mylog) {
                        System.out.println(s);
                    }
                }
            });

            panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
            panel.add(jsp);
            panel.add(btn);
            return panel;
        }

        class TestTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
            private String[] columnNames = { "Firstname", "Lastname", "Age" };
            private Object[][] data = { 
                { "John", "Smith", 29},
                { "Mary", "Thomas", 63},
                { "Peter", "Jones", 48} };

            public int getColumnCount() {
                return columnNames.length;
            }

            public int getRowCount() {
                return data.length;
            }

            public String getColumnName(int col) {
                return columnNames[col];
            }

            public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
                return data[row][col];
            }

            public Class getColumnClass(int col) {
                return getValueAt(0, col).getClass();
            }

            public String getColumnClassName(int col) {
                if (col == 2) {
                    return "Integer";
                } else {
                    return "String";
                }
            }

            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                return true;
            }

            public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
                data[row][col] = value;
                fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
            }
        }

        public class TestTableCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor
                implements TableCellEditor {
            JComponent component = new JTextField();

            @Override
            public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                    boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {

                if (value != null) {
                    ((JTextField)component).setText(value.toString());
                } else {
                    ((JTextField)component).setText("");
                }

                if (isSelected) {
                    mylog.add(value.toString() + ": row/col("+row+"/"+column+")");
                }

                return (JTextField)component;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getCellEditorValue() {
                int size = mylog.size();
                if (size > 0) {
                    Object val = mylog.get(size - 1);
                    if ((((JTextField)component).getText().equals(val))) {
                        mylog.remove(size - 1);
                    }
                }
                return ((JTextField)component).getText();
            }

        }

        public class TestTableCellRenderer extends JLabel implements 
                    TableCellRenderer {

            public TestTableCellRenderer() {
                this.setOpaque(true);
            }

            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                    boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, final int row, int column) {

                DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
                Component c = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,
                        isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
                if (hasFocus) {
                    c.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                }
                TestTableModel tm = (TestTableModel)table.getModel();
                int col = table.convertColumnIndexToModel(column);
                String colname = tm.getColumnName(col);
                String type = tm.getColumnClassName(col);

                if (type.equals("Integer") || type.equals("Int")) {
                    ((JLabel)c).setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
                } else {    // add padding 
                    ((JLabel)c).setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 10, 0, 10));
                    ((JLabel)c).setHorizontalAlignment(LEFT);
                }

                if (type.equals("String")) {
                    String text = ((JLabel)c).getText();
                        ((JLabel)c).setToolTipText(text);
                }
               return c;
            }
        }        

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new TestFocus();
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Comment: Ok, in my testing, I could click a cell, change it's content and click another cell and have the value updated by the table ... not sure I understand your particular issue

Comment: I want to be able to save the initial cell value on exiting the cell only if the value was changed.  Pressing the Done button shows the cells that have changed.  The changes are not saved if I simply click the cell, make a change and exit.  I have to tab into the cell before clicking it.  I want to make a simple undo/redo function by saving initial cell contents that get changed by the user.

Comment: In an attempt to have the clicked cell get the focus, I added:
    table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
            Point point = me.getLocationOnScreen();
            Component c = table.getComponentAt(point);  // returns null
            c.requestFocus();
        }
    });